# SAS - Do a loop while a column value doesn't change

Tags: loops, sas, do-while

I'm trying via SAS guide to use a loop (via PROC LOOP) to create a new column with a increment ID whenever the value of a specific column changes.

Just for example I'm looking for something like this:

```
Date     | Name  | Status   | ID
------------------------------------------
20150101 | Tiago | Single   | 1

20150102 | Tiago | Single   | 1

20150103 | Tiago | Married  | 2

20150104 | Tiago | Divorced | 3

20150105 | Tiago | Divorced | 3

20150106 | Tiago | Married  | 4
```

In this case, the new column will be the ID, that will increment whenever the status changes along the records. With this I can then group by name, to see every change that occurred in time (even if they are repeated).

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/faq/enumerate.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand Dajun's answer to work with grouping by name.

```
/* Sort so that name forms groups and id will go in date order */
proc sort data = test;
    by name date;
run;

data want;
    set test;
    /* Tell SAS we want to know when the value of name or status changes */
    by name status notsorted;
    /* Reset the ID for each group */
    if first.name then id = 0;
    /* iterate the ID as per DaJun */
    if first.status then id + 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

This question seems a little bit confused. If the original data is already sorted with the sample data provided, a data step like this could do.

```
data new;
    set test;
    by status notsorted;
    if first.status then id + 1;
run;
```

The notsorted option is used to keep the original data. first.status will be True for the first appearance of status. id + 1 is a summary statement. The variable in the summary statement is not initialized to missing.

And by the way, what is PROC LOOP?

Comment: Hmm, based on the OP's description, you may want your `by` statement to be `by name date status`.  The sort would also require this order.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @DaJunTian but like Robert said it's only missing the "group by" name. Thanks and my apologies for the confusion in the question, I created the post during a meeting...and the PROC LOOP is nothing lol, I was trying to say PROC SQL...